# Trouble In displaying an image

Tags: android

I am Doing a program in which we are taking photos using camera a storing it in a private folder.From that it fetching images and displaying it in a grid view.on Clicking the grid view it showing the fullscreen image. 
The trouble i am facing is when the camera is in portrait mode the image quality is perfect.But If the camera is in landscape mode it showing streched image How can i overcome this.

Comment: Check resolution of image which you want to show. If is height bigger than width the show image in portrait mode. Otherwise show image in landscape mode. Is this hepful for you?

Comment: No its possible i want to display thhe image in portrait mode iitself

Comment: ImageView cannot detect if image is captured portrait or landscape. ImageView can only manage how to show image in provided space (fill, fit,...)

Comment: while saving the image into private folder set orientation as the portrait..for this you need to to some process using matrix class of android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have a look at this below code. before saving your captured image do the following process. it will save the images in portrait mode. hope this will help you.

```
 int rotation = -1;
 rotation = ((WindowManager)getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE))
                .getDefaultDisplay().getOrientation();



    Matrix rotator = new Matrix();
    switch (rotation) {
    case (Surface.ROTATION_0):
        break;
    case (Surface.ROTATION_90):
        rotator.postRotate(270);
        break;
    case (Surface.ROTATION_180):
        rotator.postRotate(180);
        break;
    case (Surface.ROTATION_270):
        rotator.postRotate(90);
        break;


    // screen_{width,height} are applied before the rotate, so we don't
    // need to change them based on rotation.
    bmp_ss = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp_ss, 0, 0, screen_width, screen_height, rotator, false);
```